# Has Windows 10 update wiped my linux partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Till last night i was running a dual boot Linux mint 17 and Windows 10 on my hard drive, mostly using Linux and Windows only 5% of the time. Last night i turned Windows on for the first time in good 2-3 month, of course it started automated update (maybe upgrade?!) it was late so i left it there to finish up and when i turned my laptop on this morning i had:

**Error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
Grub Rescue>**

No access to Windows or Linux

I had live linux usb and through that i've been searching internet for solution - nothing worked so far and i'm starting to get a little scared that windows wiped my linux partition as when i go to Disks & Gparted  i cant see any linux partitions apart from Swap and unallocated free space!!!

I've tried using Boot repair - it finishes and lets me know all is fine.

I've tried changing the boot partition (have about 5) with all partitions returning unknown file system.

I've spent over 8 hours researching and am unable to find a solution.

So i'd like to know - have i lost all my data from linux ( i can stil mount windows partition though linux live), if so can i recover anything? 
Can i get into windows, finish the update somehow and then install linux again?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice provided

P.S. Below is a link to screenshot of Disk & Gparted 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/HRXKdIScBUBD10kE3

Comment: Questions related to windows are off topic. So are questions related to versions that are NOT official or current Ubuntu.  I would start with a "boot repair" and see if Windows only removed grub.

Comment: MInt is off topic here.

Comment: Off topic, as commented already. That said, the way to avoid this is to install both OSes in UEFI mode, as it should be always whenever available.

Comment: Right, apologies, i'll pop over to linux mint forum. I naively thought both systems are similar when it comes to repair/installation issues. Thanks for quick replies in any case

Comment: Chances are your Mint installation still exists, but GRUB has been disrupted in some way. Posting the URL provided by Boot Repair would help; without it, people can only guess as to the root cause. It's possible that my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R would enable the system to boot. As others have said, Mint is off-topic here, so you should take these suggestions as a way to improve your question on a Mint forum. (Mint is derived from Ubuntu; the off-topic nature of Mint here is policy, not technical.)

Comment: Windows 10 Anniversary Update, and the more recent Windows 10 Creators Update, are known to wipe Linux partitions on occasion... mostly on MBR format disks.

Answer (score 1):

When using `dd` to erase a USB on `/dev/sdd` I accidentally used `/dev/sdb` and wiped out the first 1 MB of my second hard disk. This erased the MBR (Master Boot Record) and partition table.

**TestDisk** can be downloaded [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and has versions for Windows and Linux. It goes through every byte of your hard drive to analyze what partition type it is and rebuilds the partition tables. I used TestDisk to successfully recover all my data.

From the website, TestDisk can:

- Fix partition table, recover deleted partition
- Recover FAT32 boot sector from its backup
- Rebuild FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 boot sector
- Fix FAT tables
- Rebuild NTFS boot sector
- Recover NTFS boot sector from its backup
- Fix MFT using MFT mirror
- Locate ext2/ext3/ext4 Backup SuperBlock
- Undelete files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem
- Copy files from deleted FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions.