# Recover data because I wiped out GPT data structure on the wrong disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery, gpt, gdisk

I wanted to install ubuntu on dual boot on my computer, but when I was doing the installation, I got "This computer currently has no detected operating systems". 
The issue is well explain here : http://linuxbsdos.com/2013/02/26/zap-gpt-data-structures-from-a-disk-while-preserving-existing-mbr-partitions/?fbclid=IwAR04J4Q1Cdf7wSwJrV6zKZ5M5zxaOsWiS_CofuBLoI5-P5fFyXPwN0HKbLw
Based on that link, "it appears that the SSD had GPT partitions on it before Windows was installed. So the GPT data structures were confusing Ubiquity." and "Presence of MBR and GPT partition tables on the same SSD. That’s why Ubuquity got confused.
GPT Partitions gdisk"

So I followed the tutorial, which the goal was to wipe out the GPT data structure and keep the MBR structure.

Unfortunatly (I know, it's my fault), it appears that when I wiped out the GPT data structure, it wasn't my C: disk, but it was my E: disk.

So now, I have a C: disk with windows on it, which is functional, like before.
And I have not my E: disk anymore.

First question : What should I do to "reconnect" my E: disk ?
Second question : When I wiped out the GPT data structure, did I remove all the datas on the disk ? Can I recover them ?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just restore from your backups?

Comment: I don't have any backups of my datas

Comment: Did you read the installation instructions? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.68377367.747785030.1554342770-173082499.1554342770#1 says "Make sure you have a recent backup of your data. While it's unlikely that anything will go wrong, you can never be too prepared".

Comment: Thank you for this usefull comment ! I'm sure it will help to get back my datas

Comment: if your data (not datas) were important to you, you would have taken backups.You didn't even bother to read the manual. Why are you complaining when people point out your own failings?

Comment: I ask a question to get a solution or some explainations to better understand the problem. I found the solution by myself, and for sure, not thanks to you, but thanks to the reading of a lot of other same questions where people were giving usefull answers. Ty for your expertise and to correct my english. Again, I'm sure it's the most important here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using testdisk to find the missing partition thank to the MBR partition table, then I saved the partition structure.
Then I converted the MBR into GPT.

Here is a 'step by step' tutorial : https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: `testdisk` saved my data too in a similar situation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/941036/has-windows-10-update-wiped-my-linux-partition/941043#941043